# Is there a way to create React Components without ES6 classes and pre compiling tools like Babel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, ecmascript-5

I got started learning React. After reading the documentation, it seems that the regular approach to create components is using ES6 classes:

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Now, I was wondering if is there a way to create components without ES6 and precompiling tools such as Babel. React documentation suggests that you use a library called `create-react-class`:

```
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var Greeting = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
});
```

But this also requires you to use Node and compile your code at the end.

What I'm looking for is a way to use ES5 only with no dependencies at all. There the React.createClass` which would work perfectly, but it's deprecated after all.

Another approach would be using just plain functions, but on this case I would not have the benefit of hooks like `componentDidMount`.

So, does anyone have a solution or suggestion for this? Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: https://medium.com/@to_pe/how-to-add-react-to-a-simple-html-file-a11511c0235f

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use node you can just include the [CDN's](https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#using-a-cdn) in the browser and use createClass.

Here are the CDN's:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Check out: [React without ES6](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html)

Edit:
As @Sidney said you will also need [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: In addition, you'd also need to use [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: @Dakota thanks for the info, but isn't `createClass` deprecated? Is it ok to still use it right now?

Comment: If you want to fulfill all your requirements you aren't going to be able to use the newest version of React. You are probably going to have to use an older one. If you have this many restrictions you might want to think about not using React at all.

Comment: All major browser except everyone's favorite problem child (IE) support ES6 classes so I wouldn't be too concerned about using them.

Comment: Alternatively you could try to find a cdn for react-create-class and use that in conjunction with React, but at that point you might as well just get the babel cdn and use it instead.

Comment: @Dakota ES6 browser support is a big concern, unless you're willing to make the website unusable for 5-15% of users (mileage may vary depending on the demographics).

Comment: I mean if hes just trying to learn going through all this just to get an example project to work on IE is kind of a waste of time. If it's production they should be using a build system (eslint, babel, etc.) to be as productive as possible.